# Records from Table not showing up in Form

Tags: ms-access

I have a FORM that is linked to a TABLE. The table has data that was entered using the form. Each time I open the form I am able to enter a new record.

However if at a later date I want to go back to the form and edit that data I can't. When I open the form I am not seeing the records from the table.

There are no filters on...I tried the "snapshot view" and the records show up in the form but I can't make any edits...take off the snapshot and the records disappear.

So my question...how can I view all the records from the table when I open the form??

RMS

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like your form is in data entry mode. In form design, press F4 to show the properties list. On the data tab, change `Data Entry` to No. Then the form will show all the records in the table but you can add a new record by pressing the rightmost navigation button.

Comment: Confirmed! This ended up solving the issue for me. Thank you for the help.